# Force activate component in Vue js component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

In my app I have a series of tabs that, when switched between, render different components. The tabs are managed by a `state` variable and a set of `v-if` directives.

These are wrapped in a `keep-alive` directive.

The first tab shows on app load, so is `activated` by default until the user tabs away.

I need to `activate` the content of the other tabs as well on app load (as the app is a collaborative workspace and other users may already have tabbed to those other tabs, and the components within need to communicate).

Is it possible to 'force' activation of tabs, then make them inactive, on app load?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. No, other users on different networks on different computers, sharing a WebRTC connection for comms. One of the components (in the 2nd tab) needs to be activated to start listening to events on that connection.

Comment: if so, display one icon or something if someone else click other tabs. you don’t need to activate all tabs, just give one signal to notice the user.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean? If the app loads, and user A clicks on Tab 2 and performs an action in the 'Tab 2' component, and user B hasn't clicked that tab yet, there's no corresponding component to communicate with.

Comment: Would v-show rather than v-if work in your case? Instead of removing the element from the DOM it creates it, but hides it if the value is false.

Comment: That might be the way forward! Thanks @user3357118